# how to calculate a sum of an array in an object

Tags: javascript

I had a variable like that

```js
const data = { 
  code: 1, 
  items: [
    { nickname: 1, name: [
      {id : "A"},
      {id : "B"}
      ] 

    },
    {
      nickname: 2, name: [
        {id: "A"},
        {id: "C"}
        ]
    }
    ] 
}
```

after that, I want to show how many characters: A:2, B:1, C:1

Comment: So, I suppose to use reduce function ...

Comment: `.map()` and `.flat()` to create the array `[ 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C' ]`. Then just `.reduce()` that into a counting object using .`.hasOwnProperty()` or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that is following steps:

- Use `flatMap()` on the array `data.items`
- Inside `flatMap()` use `map()` to convert all the object to their `id` and return it from `flatMap()`. This way you will array `["A","B","A","C"]`
- Then use `reduce()` and get an object with count of all the letters.

```js
const data = { code: 1, items: [ { nickname: 1, name: [ {id : "A"}, {id : "B"} ] }, { nickname: 2, name: [ {id: "A"}, {id: "C"} ] } ] }

const res = data.items.flatMap(x => 
                     x.name.map(a => a.id)
                   ).reduce((ac,a) => (ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1,ac),{});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Small typo in array in point two `["A","B","A","B"]` should be `["A","B","A","C"]`
Otherwise clear answer that explains what each step is doing.

Comment: Is there any reason for using `flatMap` and `reduce` instead of a single `reduce`? Other than simplification, of course.

Comment: @briosheje No there is no specific reason.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const data = {
  code: 1,
  items: [
    {
      nickname: 1, 
      name: [
        { id: "A" },
        { id: "B" }
      ]
    },
    {
      nickname: 2, 
      name: [
        { id: "A" },
        { id: "C" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const res = data.items.reduce((acc, next) => {
  next.name.forEach(({ id }) => {
    acc[id] = acc[id] + 1 || 1;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

You can do that in a single shot using `reduce`.
Reducing `data.items` will allow you to add to the accumulator (initially an empty object), the value of the currently looped `name` property item.

The result will be an object owning all the occurences of each encountered letter in the  `name` property of each array.

Relevant lines explained:

- `data.items.reduce((acc, next)` will call the reduce method on `data.items`. `acc` is the reduce accumulator (initially an empty object), `next` is the currently looped `item` of `data.items`.
- `next.name.forEach(({id})` in this line, we loop the `name` property of the currently looped item (`data.items[n]`). `({id})` is a short syntax to acquire the `id` property of the looped item in the foreach. It's equivalent to (item => item.id).
- `acc[id] = acc[id] + 1 || 1;` tries to increase the property [id] of the accumulator (example: "A" of {}) by 1. If it does not exist, it sets the value to 1.
- `return acc;` returns the accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate name and take id in a loop for assigning the count.

```js
const
    data = { code: 1, items: [{ nickname: 1, name: [{ id : "A" }, { id : "B" }] }, { nickname: 2, name: [{ id: "A" }, { id: "C" }] }] },
    result = data.items.reduce(
        (r, { name }) => (name.forEach(({ id }) => r[id] = (r[id] || 0 ) + 1), r),
        {}
    );
    
console.log(result);
```